# Load files into a blob to zip and upload

Tags: javascript, blob, plupload

I want to add all files to a blob and zip then upload using plupload.

I've googled for days looking for answer and have not been able to figure it out.

```
uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {

    plupload.each(files,function(file) {

        source = file.getSource();
        relative_path = source.relativePath
        var fileCount = up.files.length;
        var ids = $.map(up.files, function (item) { return item.id; });
        alert(source);

        arrayFiles[index] = source;

        if (index + 1 == files_remaining){
            output = pako.gzip(arrayFiles , {to : "Uint8Array"});
            myBlob = new Blob(arrayFiles);

            uploader.addFile(myBlob);
            index = 0;
        }                  
        index++;
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Mox and Brandon.

Comment: I'm not familiar with those libraries, but what is the problem with your code?

Comment: It's not adding the file to the blob.

Comment: I would also like to delete the file from the queue once it's added to the blob.

Comment: Where is `arrayFiles` declared? and `index`? Also, seems like you put the zip into `output` but you send the array itself (not the zip) to the `Blob`.

Comment: the vars are declared at the beginning of the script.. and I changed output to the Blob and it still don't work

Comment: Any errors in the `console`?

Comment: I see no errors.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at `myBlob = new Blob(arrayFiles);` is the browser ever stops?

Comment: I changed it to  var myBlob = new Blob([arrayFiles], {type: 'application/zip'}); and it does upload a zip file but it is corrupt and won't unzip.

Comment: Because it's not zip file :) what about taking the zip file (`output`) and also set the blob type to zip?

Comment: Tried changing Blob to  myBlob = new Blob(output, {type: "application/zip"}); and the browser hangs when it reaches that point.

Comment: Ok. My last shot, try changing to `myBlob = new Blob([output], {type: "application/zip"});` - first argument maybe should be an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob#Syntax

Comment: ok this does create the zip file but when opened its empty.. output = pako.gzip([arrayFiles] , {to : "application/zip"});
   
    myBlob = new Blob([output], {type: "application/zip"});

Comment: If `arrayFiles` actually contains the files (can you nake sure?) so it's already array so you probably need to pass it as is to the `gzip` function just like you did at the begging (`pako.gzip(arrayFiles , {to : "Uint8Array"})`).

Comment: We talked only on the Blob constructor that should put in array, not the gzip.